# From full path to file, to only displaying filename

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert a full path

```
C:\some folder\another folder\my-picture.jpg
```

To:

```
my-picture.jpg
```

??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it only need to work with Windows paths?

Comment: Yes, because it's only IE that displays C:\fakepath\

Comment: `C:\fakepath\ ` is also a windows path.  And all browsers are capable of displaying it.  They're also capable of displaying other types of paths like `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read from the final `\` (also works for bare `"file.ext"`);

```
var fn = "C:\\some folder\\another folder\\my-picture.jpg";
alert( fn.substr(fn.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) );
```

Comment: This is better than the `split` method IMO

Comment: @Xeon06, ran it with 10,000 loops and split was 1ms slower. I do not think there is a major performance boost with this method.

Comment: @epascarello I think at a greater scale it would make an impact. IE, you have a big array of paths that each have a lot of directories in it. But for normal every day queries you're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "C:\\some folder\\another folder\\my-picture.jpg";
var fileName = str.split("\\").pop();
```

if you need to handle different OS file paths

```
var str = "C:\\some folder\\another folder\\my-picture.jpg";
var fileName = str.split(/[\\\/]/).pop();
```